# Loader.io - PHP, curl and json

Tags: php, curl, php-7

I'm evaluating loader.io for a client and I'm having issues getting the APi to work correctly. I'm on PHP 7
http://docs.loader.io/api/v2/post/tests.html#url-options

I'm stuck on 'create test'.

The docs say:

```
curl -X POST -H 'loaderio-auth: API_KEY' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"test_type":"cycling",               "total": 6000,               "duration":60,               "urls": [                 {"url": "http://gonnacrushya.com"} ]}' https://api.loader.io/v2/tests
```

That's great! When I add my APi Key and correct URL, it runs just fine, the test is created.

Buuuut..

I want to do this in ajax via a Symfony2 app.

Here's what I've got that's returning the error:

```
urls param has incorrect format

function myAjaxCalledFunction() {
    $test_data = '{"test_type":"cycling", "total": 10, "duration":5, "urls": [{"url": "http://www.my-configured-url.com"}] }';
    return $this->doCurlRequest('tests', 'POST', $test_data);
}


public function doCurlRequest($what_call, $request = 'GET', $post_data = null)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.loader.io/v2/' . $what_call);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('loaderio-auth: ' . $this->loader_api_key));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $post_data );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return new Response($response);
 }
```

is there a curl_setopt() that I'm missing?

Comment: I should point out that list tests, run tests... all work via ajax and the function above (I took out some it $post_data is set code for simplicity here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting option `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` twice. That's why it is ignoring the first one. You can push both of them into the array like below example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array('loaderio-auth: ' . $this->loader_api_key,
          'Content-type: application/json'));
```